# ConnectableObservable Dispose all the subscribed methods at once?

Tags: c#, timer, system.reactive

so i have a game server every player has a timer so like:

```
this.player.Timer = from tick in TimerPublisher where tick % 1 == 0 select tick;
```

and i have some subscribed methods like:

```
this.player.Timer.Subscribe( tick => IncreseStamina() );
this.player.Timer.Subscribe( tick => IncresePower() );
//etc
```

so what i want to do is instead of setting

```
IDisposable dis = //the subscribed method;
```

so i can say

```
dis.Dispose(); //so it Dispose that method
```

i want away to Dispose all my subscribed methods at once can i do that?

Comment: What type of object is Timer? it is an enumerable property / collection of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IDisposable dis = new CompositeDisposable(new []
{
    this.player.Timer.Subscribe(tick => IncreseStamina()),
    this.player.Timer.Subscribe(tick => IncresePower()),
    //etc
});
```

Then you can write:

```
dis.Dispose();
```

Easy, huh?